# Why does getchar wait after one character is entered?

Tags: c, input, getchar

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
        char a = getchar();
        printf("char: %c", a);
}
```

I'm compiling this with `gcc`.

When running, the program waits for input even after one character is entered on console. Shouldn't it immediately exit and print the character? I'm running this on Ubuntu for Windows, if that can make any difference.

Comment: Are you asking about the enter required?

Comment: Yes, the program waits until a newline is received

Comment: Because until you press enter, the terminal has not yet sent any data to the program.

Answer (score 7):

`stdin` is your default input stream. The default buffering mode of `stdin` is line buffered. So it waits for the `\n` to be entered. Then only there is something to read from the input stream and then `getchar` gets the input and works with it.

Answer (score 4):

The operating system often buffers console input until a new line is entered, such that your program will not even receive the single character before. Probably nothing you can do about that.